# Selecting a value from <md-select> tag using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver and working on automating an AngularJS Web App on Chrome. It was going pretty well until I hit a dropdown list on the app.
My test keeps crashing everytime I try to select a value from it. I have been doing my research on this and I have only seen 2 solutions (both of which I have tried but don't work)

1. Use the `Select` object. This doesn't work because the html tag is not `<select>`, its `<md-select>` and this fails the test.
2. I then tried to just click on the dropdown element and click on the value - `driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to dropdown list")).click();` and `driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath do dropdown value")).click();`

With example 2, I also tried creating it as a `WebElement` variable and calling `click()` separate, but this did not work either.

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

### Update

**HTML for the dropdown list**

```
<div ng-switch-when="dropdown" class="ng-scope">
    <zf-form-dropdown>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div layout="row">
                <div flex="50" class="quote-label">
                    <p ng-bind-html="::label" class="ng-binding">Title</p>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="false" flex="10" class="tooltip-icon ng-hide" ng-click="showToolTip(field.get('toolTip'))" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true"><img src="img/item-question@2x.png"></div>

                <md-select flex="" ng-disabled="quote.isRated() || !input.enabled" ng-change="onDropdownChange()" ng-model="input.value" class="ng-valid md-default-theme ng-touched ng-dirty" role="combobox" id="select_0Q9" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="select_label_0I1" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-owns="select_menu_0Q8"><md-select-label class="md-select-label md-placeholder" id="select_label_0I1"><span></span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-label></md-select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </zf-form-dropdown>
</div>
```

**HTML for the value I want to select**

```
<md-option ng-value="::item.val" ng-selected="item.checked" ng-repeat="item in getOpts()" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_0QD" value="MR">
    <div class="md-text ng-binding">Mr</div>
    <div class="md-ripple-container"></div>
</md-option>
```

The xpath for the dropdown list is `//*[@id="select_0Q9"]`
The xpath for the dropdown value is `//*[@id="select_option_0QD"]`

Comment: About the second approach: are you getting any error(s)? What is happening?

Comment: The only error I am seeing is from the Failure Trace on JUnit, and that is a NoSuchElementException. I have seen this and must have rechecked this over 5 times and the xpath is correct

Comment: Can you provide the HTML representation of the dropdown and the expressions you've used?

Comment: I have included the html for the dropdown and value. The expression I have used was `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select_0Q9\"]")).click();` to click on the dropdown

Comment: When you click the dropdown, does it actually open? Maybe the click needs to go onto another element?

Comment: Have you tried to click on `<div class="dropdown">`

Comment: @Striker I tried your suggestion. It didn't crash but it also didn't work. You see the layout has a rectangular box that displays `Title` and then the rectangular box beside it is the dropdown list. `<div class="dropdown">` covers both the 2 rectangular boxes. I am surprised `click()` method didn't crash? The `<md-select>` tag is now where the focus is entirely on the dropdown list

Comment: click method never crashes unless on an element not enabled or not displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your Xpath is fine then you can also click using javascriptexecutor so try it out like below:-

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//md-option[@id='select_option_0QD']/div[1]"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Please feel free to locate the element in above code as per your convenience .

As per me your xpath of dropdown should be like below:-

```
//md-option[@id='select_option_0QD']
```

And xpath of first div which I suppose want to click is:-

```
//md-option[@id='select_option_0QD']/div[1]
```

Change [1] to  [2] if you want 2nd value.

In an another aspect you can also store all your element in the list(As you know you can't use select) and click them as per your need or all.

For that you need to use xpath like:-

```
//md-option[@id='select_option_0QD']/div
```

Now implement it into code:-

```
List<WebElement> allelemts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//md-option[@id='select_option_0QD']/div"));
  for(WebElement ele: allelemts){

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//md-option[@id='select_option_0QD']")).click();

    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);

  }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for your very descriptive response. I have tried what you suggested but it still does not work :( I done a bit of debugging and seen that is is crashing on the creation of the `WebElement element` object variable. I did not call `click()` and it still crashed with a NoSuchElementException. This is really confusing as the element is clearly there and works when I do it manually, but crashes everytime I try to automate

Comment: you can wait as @justcurious shown in tthere answer. Another thing is to check whether do you have any frame in your HTML DOM. If yes then you have to switch to frame first

Comment: Just after trying @justcurious solution and that does not work as I have got a TimeoutException. I will have a look for the frame and see if there is one

Comment: you need to increase the time if your element is loading late.. As juscurious is using onlu 20 or 10 sec.. try to increase it first for 50-60 sec. if it works then decrease it at the point where script run fine.

Comment: Apologies, I should have stated that I did increase the time. I started out at 20 and increased up to 180, and it still times out

Answer (score 1):

Since you are receiving a `NoSuchElementException` exception, I believe the issue lies in Selenium not able to identify the element. Try any of the following `wait` methods and then try to click the element.

**Explicit Wait:** (Most Preferred)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("elementID")));
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("elementID")));
```

**Implicit Wait:**

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

**Sleep:** (Try to avoid this unless absolutely necessary)

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

**EDIT:** Added code to check for element's presence using `findElements` method.

Before using any of these `wait` methods you could also check for the presence of your element using `findElements` method.

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.id("elementId"));
    if (element.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
    } else{
            System.out.println("Element found");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solutions both `elementToBeClickable()` and `presenceOfElement()`. Both caused a TimeoutException. I think this happened due to the fact that the visible element can't be found. I am really dumbfounded by this issue :(

Comment: Did you try to confirm the element's presence by `findElements` method?

Comment: Yes I make a List of WebElements and it is empty everytime

Comment: There you have it. As I suggested earlier, the real issue here is Selenium not able to identify the element. This test with `findElements` leaves us with 2 possibilities: 1) May be the DOM containing the element is not completely loaded before Selenium tries to click it 2) Element is inside a different frame, in which case you need to do a `driver.Switchto()` to get into that frame and click the element.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a good practice, but just for the sake of identifying the element, try using `Thread.Sleep()` before clicking it and see if the element is identified.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved the issue!

I got the Selenium IDE and recorded a session where I got as far as selecting the dropdown menu and selecting my value. I then exported the file as a java test case and was able to read the lines where it selected the values, and they were;

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#select_08D > #select_label_005 > span.md-select-icon")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("select_option_08H")).click();
```

So first off they both do not use `xpath` to find the elements, the dropdown menu itself is found with the `cssSelector` and the value is found by the `id`.

I am just cross referencing again and the `id` for the value is `select_option_08H` but while I am looking at Google Console I can see the `id` for the value is `select_option_189`

Comment: is there any way to do this by selecting the item by text? The generated IDs seem pretty brittle.